# How would civilization develop on Earth-like planet that has no axial tilt?

Tags: climate, civilization, agriculture

**Premise:** Let's assume that this planet is in state of perpetual equinox, that is the result of no tilt to its axis and that this world orbits the same sun as ours within the same distance. From what I've read, no axis tilt would result in uniform climate around whole planet, allowing crop harvests throught the whole year. Let's also assume this climate is warmer and more humid and there are no ice caps at the poles (climate basicly similiar to Eocene Optimum). There is also a land at the north pole, about 700 km in diameter. The rest of landmass resemble that of our own. The world is inhabited by humans species that live much longer than us.

**Civilization. How would it develop, or would it at all?** I think the biggest factor in this would be that the food in this world is in abundance. I imagine this hypothetical eternal spring would make agriculture obsolete. Why should you toil the land, if there's plenty of wild crops, fruits and game in the forests?

Comment: "Uniform climate" across the year, not across the latitudes... And civilization started in warm climates anyway, such as Egypt and Mesopotamia, were there is no actual winter anyway.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Worldbuilding! As it currently stands, this is a very broad question and so, may get put on hold as such. I suggest that you edit the question so that you're only asking one question per 'question post'. Thanks

Comment: Do try and narrow this down. This is an interesting topic, but a question that asks how civilization would develop in this way is basically asking people to make up whole scenarios for you.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.  As the others said, this is very broad right now.  I've put this question on hold temporarily; please [edit] to narrow the focus and then the community will review for possible reopening.  You're welcome to ask additional questions separately (though it's usually a good idea to ask them one at a time so you can apply what you learn from earlier ones).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An Earth-like planet lacking an axial tilt would have incredibly little variation in climate and therefore few global weather patterns.  There could still be some forms of air and water circulation because the planet is still spinning, but their movement would not be accompanied by the significant changes in heat and moisture levels that can drive catastrophes like hurricanes.  Intense sunlight would also affect all cultures globally, and the concept of a "year" would be highly theoretical (those navel-gazers keeping track of the stars) rather than grounded in a seasonal cycle essential to the material wellbeing of all.  The length of day and night is absolute in this world.  There are no long winter nights, no recurring sense of having more time in the light then less then more again.  I think change might be viewed as more linear than cyclical.  Perhaps people would tend to be more afraid of change because they are not used to it, or perhaps they would be less afraid of change because they are not conditioned to the highly predictable one of seasons.

Changes in the magnetosphere when poles shift have huge impacts on geology and evolution.  If the axis never "wobbles", does it just flip every so often?  In a world where all points on the globe receive the full intensity of sunlight, this could have especially deleterious effects.  When the poles shift, there is momentary exposure to greater radiation since the planet loses the protective field of the magnetosphere.  Our last pole reversal here on Earth was about 800k years ago.  In terms of the evolution of hominids, this likely occurred before the first Homo sapiens but soon after Homo erectus and Homo ergaster began to harness fire and build simple machines.  I don't know of any anthropologist who thinks the pole shift had any role in the development of civilization, but this is fiction so it's fun to imagine.  What if that pole shift on Earth contributed to the speciation of Homo sapiens due to mutations from increased radiation?  Maybe in this tilt-free Earth you'll find multiple, closely related intelligent species, with biological differences contributing to different cultures in the absence of climactic variation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Civilization would develop pretty much the same as it did.

First I upvote AlexP's comment: The uniform climate is across the YEAR, it is not uniform from the north pole to the south pole. So there is still **some** variation, and that civilization started in warm climates anyway; the middle East basically.

If the entire Earth is habitable and arable, the same organization would occur. Hunter gatherers most likely **accidentally** invented farming, by carrying fruits and edible plants collected in one place with them, and discarding the rinds or seeds on fertile ground. Since many HG groups make circuits of a large area of land; all it takes is a normal human memory to realize that primitive versions of squash or cucumbers or watermelon or cantaloupes are growing exactly where you ate the same thing a year ago. And spit out the seeds. *Eureka!* The invention of intentional farming.

Which could be accomplished still by HG, or herders (an evolution of HG into tribes with goats, sheep or cattle they drive on a circuit to consume fresh vegetation). They can scatter seeds at each campsite in their circuit; and move on to the next: Hopefully harvesting some of whatever they scattered there last year, on their previous visit.

But eventually farming becomes "institutional" in the sense that a tribe creates a permanent settlement and plants a large amount of high calorie food (like grain) and stays to protect it. Probably a **herding** tribe; since they can also protect land for grazing, build corrals and more permanent shelters (instead of tents), making animal tending easier and life more comfortable. Also, 95% of food plants like grains are not consumed by people, but will be consumed by goats. (Goats can eat and get energy from nearly all vegetation, including roots, stalks, rinds and even branches, and goats are not picky at all. Plus they produce high calorie milk and meat: Making them an ideal first domestic animal.)

Specialization (of jobs) and Civilization springs forth. Probably even ***faster*** and in ***more*** places than it did on Earth, where we had the complicating factor of dealing with seasons, winters, and harsh summers.

The seasons did not drive us to form settlements. We formed settlements because we found much easier ways of getting meat (herding) and much easier ways of getting calories (farming) and settlement was much easier than carrying everything five miles every day. Once you figure out how to get your calories with very little effort, you stop working so hard to get calories, and start working on other things. Like music, then flush toilets, then inventing the Internet. (In that order.)

Comment: Gatherers typically settle to let their beer ripen. _That_ lead them to farming.

Comment: @user58697 That is a speculative myth. There is archaeological and anthropological evidence of intentional farming by herders long before the Egyptians were planting grains for alcohol on the Nile. Where do you think they got the idea for that in the first place? Farming almost certainly ***evolved*** from early accidental beginnings; there is even evidence that patches of certain flowers were intentionally planted near good campsites by herders, perhaps to mark the spot. (trenching shows the seeds suddenly appearing in a large area at a specific time.)